# How to integrate Next js with Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I am using Next js and Material UI(@mui/core) to create a website. It is working completely fine when I am running it using `next dev`, but am getting the wrong styles when I am using `next build && next start`. Along with Material UI, I am using CSS Modules to style my application. 
I found a solution on Github that said to add this code in `_document.js`, but this is not working for me.

```
import * as React from "react";
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import createEmotionServer from "@emotion/server/create-instance";
import theme from "../src/theme";
import createEmotionCache from "../src/createEmotionCache";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          {/* PWA primary color */}
          <meta name="theme-color" content={theme.palette.primary.main} />
          <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/favicon.ico" />
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
          />
          {/* Inject MUI styles first to match with the prepend: true configuration. */}
          {this.props.emotionStyleTags}
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

// `getInitialProps` belongs to `_document` (instead of `_app`),
// it's compatible with static-site generation (SSG).
MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  // Resolution order
  //
  // On the server:
  // 1. app.getInitialProps
  // 2. page.getInitialProps
  // 3. document.getInitialProps
  // 4. app.render
  // 5. page.render
  // 6. document.render
  //
  // On the server with error:
  // 1. document.getInitialProps
  // 2. app.render
  // 3. page.render
  // 4. document.render
  //
  // On the client
  // 1. app.getInitialProps
  // 2. page.getInitialProps
  // 3. app.render
  // 4. page.render

  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

  // You can consider sharing the same emotion cache between all the SSR requests to speed up performance.
  // However, be aware that it can have global side effects.
  const cache = createEmotionCache();
  const { extractCriticalToChunks } = createEmotionServer(cache);

  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: (App) =>
        function EnhanceApp(props) {
          return <App emotionCache={cache} {...props} />;
        },
    });

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
  // This is important. It prevents emotion to render invalid HTML.
  // See https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/26561#issuecomment-855286153
  const emotionStyles = extractCriticalToChunks(initialProps.html);
  const emotionStyleTags = emotionStyles.styles.map((style) => (
    <style
      data-emotion={`${style.key} ${style.ids.join(" ")}`}
      key={style.key}
      // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-danger
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: style.css }}
    />
  ));

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    emotionStyleTags,
  };
};
```

Comment: You have an exemple of integration here https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/HEAD/examples/nextjs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

clone this repository
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs
and make sure that you have update your _app.js and add createEmotionCache if you are using emotion.
and for styling your elements try to use material ui styles instead of CSS Modules

Answer (score 0):

Here's the another example usage: https://github.com/ilhammeidi/luxi-starter/blob/master/pages/_app.js

I think the `createEmotionCache` is optional because it's used for layout direction LTR anr RTL. This code bellow works with MUI 5 and Next 14

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import App from 'next/app';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import createCache from '@emotion/cache';
import rtlPlugin from 'stylis-plugin-rtl';
import { prefixer } from 'stylis';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import appTheme from '../theme/appTheme';

const isBrowser = typeof document !== 'undefined';
let insertionPoint;

if (isBrowser) {
  const emotionInsertionPoint = document.querySelector(
    'meta[name="emotion-insertion-point"]',
  );
  insertionPoint = emotionInsertionPoint ?? undefined;
}

const cacheRTL = createCache({
  key: 'mui-style-rtl',
  stylisPlugins: [prefixer, rtlPlugin],
  insertionPoint,
  prepend: true,
});

const cacheLTR = createCache({
  key: 'mui-style-ltr',
  insertionPoint,
  prepend: true,
});

function MyApp(props) {
  const { Component, pageProps, router } = props;
  const themeName = 'burgundy';
  const defaultTheme = 'light';
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState({
    ...appTheme(themeName, defaultTheme),
    direction: 'ltr',
  });

  const muiTheme = createTheme(theme);
  return (
    <CacheProvider value={theme.direction === 'rtl' ? cacheRTL : cacheLTR}>
      <Head>
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no"
        />
      </Head>
      <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <div id="main-wrap">
          <Component
            {...pageProps}
            key={router.route}
          />
        </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  );
}

MyApp.propTypes = {
  Component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
  pageProps: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  router: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => ({ ...(await App.getInitialProps(appContext)) });

export default MyApp;
```